# Cant extract asterisks with my regular expression

Tags: r, regex

I have a string: *** CONNECTION WAS MADE IN MESSAGE ***

I want to extract three first words in that string with regular expression. But when i try this:

```
\\w+ \\w+(:| \\w+)
```

It extract this: CONNECTION WAS MADE, instead of *** CONNECTION WAS

What am i doing wrong here? How to fix it? What should i use instead of \w, so it extract both strings and asterisks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `\\S+` as pattern to match one or more non-whitespace character

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+")
#[1] "*** CONNECTION WAS"

str_extract(str2, "\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+")
#[1] "some random example"

str_extract(str3, "\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+")
#[1] "response message: <?xml"
```

---

According to `?regex`

> The symbol \w matches a ‘word’ character (a synonym for [[:alnum:]_], an extension)

Thus, it matches only the alphanumeric characters along with `_` and not `*`.  Also, the `*` in regex implies metacharacter that signifies zero or more

#### data

```
str1 <- "*** CONNECTION WAS MADE IN MESSAGE ***"
str2 <- "some random example message"
str3 <- 'response message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding'
```

Comment: and in case of "some random example message" would it extract "some random example" ? cause it must work for both strings and asterisks

Comment: @french_fries i updated the post.  with '\\S`

Comment: @french_fries please check my update

Comment: @french_fries it is working for me though.  please check my update